# Haskell: Can I read integers directly into an array?

Tags: arrays, performance, haskell, stdin

In [this](https://codeforces.com/contest/1606/problem/D) programming problem, the input is an `n`×`m` integer matrix. Typically, `n`≈ 10<sup>5</sup> and `m` ≈ 10. The official [solution](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/96454#:%7E:text=BledDest-,Tutorial,-Solution%20(awoo)) (1606D, Tutorial) is quite imperative: it involves some matrix manipulation, precomputation and aggregation. For fun, I took it as an STUArray implementation exercise.

### Issue

I have managed to implement it using STUArray, but still the program takes [way more memory](https://codeforces.com/contest/1606/submission/137204295) than permitted (256MB). Even when run locally, the maximum resident set size is >400 MB. On profiling, reading from stdin seems to be dominating the memory footprint:

[image: profiling]

Functions `readv` and `readv.readInt`, responsible for parsing integers and saving them into a 2D list, are **taking around 50-70 MB, as opposed to around 16 MB** = (10<sup>6</sup> integers) × (8 bytes per integer + 8 bytes per link).

Is there a hope I can **get the total memory below 256 MB?** I'm already using `Text` package for input. Maybe I should avoid lists altogether and **directly read *integers* from stdin to the array. How can we do that?** Or, is the issue elsewhere?

#### Code

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}
module CF1606D where
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TI
import qualified Data.Text.Read as TR
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.List as DL
import qualified Data.IntSet as DS
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST.Safe
import Data.Int (Int32)
import Data.Array.Unboxed

solve :: IO ()
solve =  do
  ~[n,m] <- readv      
  -- 2D list
  input <- {-# SCC input #-} replicateM (fromIntegral n) readv     
  let
      ints = [1..]
      sorted = DL.sortOn (head.fst) (zip input ints)
      (rows,indices) = {-# SCC rows_inds #-} unzip sorted    
      -- 2D list converted into matrix:
      matrix = mat (fromIntegral n) (fromIntegral m) rows           
      infinite = 10^7
      asc x y = [x,x+1..y]
      desc x y = [y,y-1..x]    
      -- Four prefix-matrices:
      tlMax = runSTUArray $ prefixMat max 0 asc asc (subtract 1) (subtract 1) =<< matrix
      blMin = runSTUArray $ prefixMat min infinite desc asc (+1) (subtract 1) =<< matrix
      trMin = runSTUArray $ prefixMat min infinite asc desc (subtract 1) (+1) =<< matrix
      brMax = runSTUArray $ prefixMat max 0 desc desc (+1) (+1) =<< matrix    
      good _ (i,j)
        | tlMax!(i,j) < blMin!(i+1,j) && brMax!(i+1,j+1) < trMin!(i,j+1) = Left (i,j)
        | otherwise = Right ()
      {-# INLINABLE good #-}
      nearAns = foldM good () [(i,j)|i<-[1..n-1],j<-[1..m-1]]
      ans = either (\(i,j)-> "YES\n" ++ color n (take i indices) ++ " " ++ show j) (const "NO") nearAns
  putStrLn ans

type I = Int32
type S s = (STUArray s (Int, Int) I)
type R = Int -> Int -> [Int]
type F = Int -> Int

mat :: Int -> Int -> [[I]] -> ST s (S s)
mat n m rows = newListArray ((1,1),(n,m)) $ concat rows

prefixMat :: (I->I->I) -> I -> R -> R -> F -> F -> S s -> ST s (S s)
prefixMat opt worst ordi ordj previ prevj mat = do
  ((ilo,jlo),(ihi,jhi)) <- getBounds mat
  pre <- newArray ((ilo-1,jlo-1),(ihi+1,jhi+1)) worst
  forM_ (ordi ilo ihi) $ \i-> do
    forM_ (ordj jlo jhi) $ \j -> do
      matij <- readArray mat (i,j)
      prei <- readArray pre (previ i,j)
      prej <- readArray pre (i, prevj j)
      writeArray pre (i,j) (opt (opt prei prej) matij)
  return pre

color :: Int -> [Int] -> String
color n inds = let
  temp = DS.fromList inds
  colors = [if DS.member i temp then 'B' else 'R' | i<-[1..n]]
  in colors

readv :: Integral t => IO [t]
readv = map readInt . T.words <$> TI.getLine where
  readInt = fromIntegral . either (const 0) fst . TR.signed TR.decimal
{-# INLINABLE readv #-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ~[n] <- readv
  replicateM_ n solve
```

**Quick description of the code above:**

1. Read `n` rows each having `m` integers.
2. Sort the rows by their first element.
3. Now compute four 'prefix matrices', one from each corner. For top-left and bottom-right corners, it's the prefix-maximum, and for the other two corners, it's the prefix-minimum that we need to compute.
4. Find a cell [i,j] at which these prefix matrices satisfy the following condition: top_left [i,j] < bottom_left [i,j] and top_right [i,j] > bottom_right [i,j]
5. For rows 1 through i, mark their original indices (i.e. position in the unsorted input matrix) as Blue. Mark the rest as Red.

**Sample input and Commands**

Sample input: [inp3.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yw5tWGAMLIabZduKAECqTTBIfVyzQ_gz/view?usp=sharing).

Command:

```
> stack ghc -- -main-is CF1606D.main -with-rtsopts="-s -h -p -P" -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto CF1606D
> gtime -v ./CF1606D < inp3.txt > outp
    ...
    ...
    MUT     time    2.990s  (  3.744s elapsed)    #    RTS -s output
    GC      time    4.525s  (  6.231s elapsed)    #    RTS -s output
    ...
    ...
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 408532    #    >256 MB (gtime output)

> stack exec -- hp2ps -t0.1 -e8in -c CF1606D.hp && open CF1606D.ps
```

**Question about GC:** As shown above in the +RTS -s output, GC seems to be taking longer than the actual logic execution. Is this normal? Is there a way to visualize the GC activity over time? I tried making matrices strict but that didn't have any impact.

Probably this is not a functional-friendly problem at all (although I'll be happy to be disproved on this). For example, **Java uses GC too but there are lots of successful Java submissions.** Still, I want to see how far I can push. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, I suspect this problem is more suited to a jagged-array representation like in the C++ solution `vector<vector<int>>`, instead of a monolithic matrix. That allows you to re-use rows or at least garbage-collecting them individually.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I hadn't thought of that. Tried that [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1606/submission/137338004). Still no early garbage-collection. In fact it's slightly worse now. Or you meant something else?

Comment: Well kind of. You'd need to use this also for the result of `prefixMat`, and the inner arrays should probably still be unboxed.

Comment: Tried doing that but ran into errors. I started by writing a utility function that's supposed to be the unboxed counterpart of listArray: `listUArray :: Ix a => (a, a) -> [e] -> UArray a e; listUArray (lo,hi) xs = runSTUArray (newListArray (lo,hi) xs)` and met with `Could not deduce (MArray (STUArray s) e (GHC.ST.ST s))`. Replacing `e` with `Int` seems to fix the issue, but replacing `e` with `UArray Int Int` brings back the error. What am I missing?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't see how making `prefixMat` results jagged helps though. They are already single copies, hence there is no scope for further re-using. Rows might be able to be garbage-collected individually but they _all_ have to wait till the end (of `foldM` call) anyway.

Comment: I'm not an expert at arrays and ST, but it looks a little suspicious to me that your `matrix` (into which you pack the ints from the lists) is a program in the `ST` monad, as opposed to the final matrix after *running* the `ST` program. You then use in 4 entirely separate `runSTUArray` calls; I'd worry that this would repeat the work of building the starting array from the lists, which means the lists can't be garbage collected. But maybe this is how you're supposed to use this API and it's actually fine.

Comment: @Ben I think I have tried that before [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1606/submission/136217281). Relevant snippet: `!mat = initialize n m numbers`, where `initialize n m numbers = runSTUArray $ newListArray ((1,1),(n,m)) numbers`. In that code I have also used `ByteString` (albeit `Lazy`) for stdin. That was no better (nor worse), had the same memory bloat issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to common belief Haskell is quite friendly with respect to problems like that. The real issue is that the `array` library that comes with GHC is total garbage. Another big problem is that everyone is taught in Haskell to use lists where arrays should be used instead, which is usually one of the major sources of slow code and memory bloated programs. So, it is not surprising that GC takes a long time, it is because there is way too much stuff being allocation. Here is a run on the supplied input for the solution provided below:

```
   1,483,547,096 bytes allocated in the heap
         566,448 bytes copied during GC
      18,703,640 bytes maximum residency (3 sample(s))
       1,223,400 bytes maximum slop
              32 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1399 colls,     0 par    0.009s   0.009s     0.0000s    0.0011s
  Gen  1         3 colls,     0 par    0.002s   0.002s     0.0006s    0.0016s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.484s  (  0.517s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.011s  (  0.011s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.496s  (  0.530s elapsed)
```

The solution provided below uses an array library [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv), which makes it impossible to submit to codeforces. However, hopefully the goal is to get better at Haskell, rather than get points on some website.

The red-blue matrix can be separated into two stages: *read* and *solve*

## Read

### Read the dimensions

In the `main` function we only read total number of arrays and dimensions for each array. Also we print the outcome. Nothing exciting here. (Note that the linked file `inp3.txt` has a larger array than the limits defined in the problem: `n*m <= 10^6`)

```hs
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Massiv.Array as A hiding (B)
import Data.Massiv.Array.Mutable.Algorithms (quicksortByM_)
import Control.Scheduler (trivialScheduler_)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  t <- Prelude.read <$> getLine
  when (t < 1 || t > 1000) $ error $ "Invalid t: " ++ show t
  replicateM_ t $ do
    dimsStr <- getLine
    case Prelude.map Prelude.read (words dimsStr) of
      -- Test file fails this check: && n * m <= 10 ^ (6 :: Int) -> do
      [n, m] | n >= 2 && m > 0 && m <= 5 * 10 ^ (5 :: Int) -> do
        mat <- readMatrix n m
        case solve mat of
          Nothing -> putStrLn "NO"
          Just (ix, cs) -> do
            putStrLn "YES"
            putStr $ foldMap show cs
            putStr " "
            print ix
      _ -> putStrLn $ "Unexpected dimensions: " ++ show dimsStr
```

### Read the array in

Loading the input into array is the major source of problems int the original question:

- there is no need to rely on `text`, ascii characters is the only valid input expected by the problem.
- input is read into a list of lists. That list of lists is the real source of the memory overhead.
- Sorting lists is ridiculously slow and memory hungry.

Normally in such situation it would be much better to read input in a streaming fashion using something like `conduit`. In particular, reading input as stream of bytes and parsing those bytes as numbers would be the optimal solution. That being said there are hard requirements on the width of each array in the description of the problem, so we can get away with reading input line-by-line as a `ByteString` and then parsing numbers (assumed unsigned for simplicity) in each line and write those numbers into array at the same time. This ensures that at this stage we will only have allocated the resulting array and a single line as sequence of bytes. This could be done cleaner with a parsing library like `attoparsec`, but problem is simple enough to just do it adhoc.

```hs
type Val = Word

readMatrix :: Int -> Int -> IO (Matrix P Val)
readMatrix n m = createArrayS_ (Sz2 n m) readMMatrix

readMMatrix :: MMatrix RealWorld P Val -> IO ()
readMMatrix mat =
  loopM_ 0 (< n) (+ 1) $ \i -> do
    line <- BS.getLine
    --- ^ reads at most 10Mb because it is known that input will be at most
    -- 5*10^5 Words: 19 digits max per Word and one for space: 5*10^5 * 20bytes
    loopM 0 (< m) (+ 1) line $ \j bs ->
      let (word, bs') = parseWord bs
       in bs' <$ write_ mat (i :. j) word
  where
    Sz2 n m = sizeOfMArray mat
    isSpace = (== 32)
    isDigit w8 = w8 >= 48 && w8 <= 57
    parseWord bs =
      case BS.uncons bs of
        Just (w8, bs')
          | isDigit w8 -> parseWordLoop (fromIntegral (w8 - 48)) bs'
          | otherwise -> error $ "Unexpected byte: " ++ show w8
        Nothing -> error "Unexpected end of input"
    parseWordLoop !acc bs =
      case BS.uncons bs of
        Nothing -> (acc, bs)
        Just (w8, bs')
          | isSpace w8 -> (acc, bs')
          | isDigit w8 -> parseWordLoop (acc * 10 + fromIntegral (w8 - 48)) bs'
          | otherwise -> error $ "Unexpected byte: " ++ show w8
```

## Solve

This is the step where we implement the actual solution. Instead of going into trying to fix the solution provided in this SO question I went on and translated the [C++ solution](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/96454) that was linked in the question instead. Reason I went that route is twofold:

- C++ soluition is highly imperative and I wanted to demonstrate that imperative array manipulations are not that foreign to Haskell, so I tried to create a translation that was as close as possible.
- I knew that solution works

Note, that it should be possible to rewrite the solution below with `array` package, because in the end all that is needed are the `read`, `write` and `allocate` operations.

```hs
computeSortBy ::
     (Load r Ix1 e, Manifest r' e)
  => (e -> e -> Ordering)
  -> Vector r e
  -> Vector r' e
computeSortBy f vec = 
  withLoadMArrayST_ vec $ quicksortByM_ (\x y -> pure $ f x y) trivialScheduler_

solve :: Matrix P Val -> Maybe (Int, [Color])
solve a = runST $ do
  let sz@(Sz2 n m) = size a
      ord :: Vector P Int
      ord = computeSortBy 
              (\x y -> compare (a ! (y :. 0)) (a ! (x :. 0))) (0 ..: n)
  mxl <- newMArray @P sz minBound
  loopM_ (n - 1) (>= 0) (subtract 1) $ \ i ->
    loopM_ 0 (< m) (+ 1) $ \j -> do
      writeM mxl (i :. j) (a ! ((ord ! i) :. j))
      when (i < n - 1) $
        writeM mxl (i :. j) 
          =<< max <$> readM mxl (i :. j) <*> readM mxl (i + 1 :. j)
      when (j > 0) $
        writeM mxl (i :. j) 
          =<< max <$> readM mxl (i :. j) <*> readM mxl (i :. j - 1)
  mnr <- newMArray @P sz maxBound
  loopM_ (n - 1) (>= 0) (subtract 1) $ \ i ->
    loopM_ (m - 1) (>= 0) (subtract 1) $ \ j -> do
      writeM mnr (i :. j) (a ! ((ord ! i) :. j))
      when (i < n - 1) $
        writeM mnr (i :. j) 
          =<< min <$> readM mnr (i :. j) <*> readM mnr (i + 1 :. j)
      when (j < m - 1) $
        writeM mnr (i :. j) 
          =<< min <$> readM mnr (i :. j) <*> readM mnr (i :. j + 1)
  mnl <- newMArray @P (Sz m) maxBound
  mxr <- newMArray @P (Sz m) minBound
  let goI i
        | i < n - 1 = do
          loopM_ 0 (< m) (+ 1) $ \j -> do
            val <- min (a ! ((ord ! i) :. j)) <$> readM mnl j
            writeM mnl j val
            when (j > 0) $
              writeM mnl j . min val =<< readM mnl (j - 1)
          loopM_ (m - 1) (>= 0) (subtract 1) $ \j -> do
            val <- max (a ! ((ord ! i) :. j)) <$> readM mxr j
            writeM mxr j val
            when (j < m - 1) $
              writeM mxr j . max val =<< readM mxr (j + 1)
          let goJ j
                | j < m - 1 = do
                    mnlVal <- readM mnl j
                    mxlVal <- readM mxl (i + 1 :. j)
                    mxrVal <- readM mxr (j + 1)
                    mnrVal <- readM mnr ((i + 1) :. (j + 1))
                    if mnlVal > mxlVal && mxrVal < mnrVal
                      then pure $ Just (i, j)
                      else goJ (j + 1)
                | otherwise = pure Nothing
          goJ 0 >>= \case
            Nothing -> goI (i + 1)
            Just pair -> pure $ Just pair
        | otherwise = pure Nothing
  mAns <- goI 0
  Control.Monad.forM mAns $ \ (ansFirst, ansSecond) -> do
    resVec <- createArrayS_ @BL (Sz n) $ \res ->
        iforM_ ord $ \i ordIx -> do
          writeM res ordIx $! if i <= ansFirst then R else B
    pure (ansSecond + 1, A.toList resVec)
```

Comment: Whoa! That was incredibly fast. I checked github to find that _you_ are the author of  `massiv`, which I find worth mentioning.

Comment: "it should be possible to rewrite the solution below with array package, because in the end all that is needed are the read, write and allocate operations." I guess that means writing `sort` on our own.

Comment: how do I compile it with profiling options? Getting the error `Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘massiv-1.0.1.1’?` I am curious to see who much memory is pinned due to `Bytestring`

Comment: @cobra Yes I am the author :) Yes it would mean writing sorting from scratch. With regards to profiling, it is unlikely that you will be able to see how much pinned memory there is allocated for ByteString, because large unboxed arrays (>3Kb) are always allocated pinned. The largest amount of memory ByteString can take up in this program is the maximum line length read from input.